# Extract src image field from a simple html string without a parser

Tags: java, android, regex

I have html strings like these:

```
<img src="mysrc" width="128" height="92" border="0" alt="alt" /><p><strong>...
```

I'd like to extract mysrc. I don't want to use an html parser as I'll just have to deal with simple html strings...is there an efficient way to extract source field just with string/regular expressions? Or maybe with android default xml parser?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Something, but no efficient idea till now..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

regex you could try : `"(?<=<img src=\")[^\"]*"`

example:

```
@Test
    public void testX() {
        final String s = "<img src=\"mysrc\" width=\"128\" height=\"92\"...";
        final String regex = "(?<=<img src=\")[^\"]*";
        final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        final Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }

    }
```

will give you

```
mysrc
```

Comment: your input String is changed?

Comment: not at all! <img src="http://source" width="128" height="92" border="0" alt="alt" title="title" /><p><strong>blabla ...

Comment: tried with your new text above, here it gave the correct text: `source`.

Comment: omg.... here's my main which gives me "no match found" : public static void main(String[] args){
  String body = "<img src=\"source\" width=\"128\" height=\"92\" border=\"0\" alt=\"alt\" title=\"title\" /><p><strong>blabla";
  final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=<img src=\")[^\"]*");
  System.out.println("**** TEXT: "+p.matcher(body).group()+" ******");
 
 }

Comment: ok it works...I didn't call find() on the matcher! Listen, in order to improve efficiency is it possible to just stop to first occurence found?

Comment: @Phate the while block is important. pls read the java doc about m.find(). add it to your code and try again. it should work.

Comment: so find() just finds first occurence and calling it over over make it go ahead, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

You could do some thing like

```
String text = "<img src=\"mysrc\" width=\"128\" height=\"92\" border=\"0\" alt=\"alt\" /><p><strong>";

text = text.substring(text.indexOf("src=\""));
text = text.substring("src=\"".length());
text = text.substring(0, text.indexOf("\""));
System.out.println(text);
```

Effective, probably, efficient, probably not so much